# How to query in two different path with same request?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For example it is simple call:

```
const stateQueryRes = await citiesRef.where('state', '==', 'CA').get();
```

But I want get cities where ‘state’ not in list of banned states (from separate document ‘bannedCitiesDoc’. This ‘bannedCitiesDoc’ is document with array of banned cities. For example:

```
const stateQueryRes = await citiesRef
.where('state', '==', 'CA')
.where('state', ‘not’-in, bannedCitiesDoc)
.get();
```

This is possible?

Comment: Seem possible: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any Did you give it a try?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for reply! I try but cannot find how to do. You can give example?

Answer (score 1):

A Firestore query can only consider documents in a single collection at a time.  It's not possible to do a SQL-like "join" between multiple collections, nor it is possible to use the contents of a document field as the input for a query filter.

If you need to work with data in two collections, you will have to make two queries.  In your case, you will have to first query for banned cities, then query for cities in a state, then filter out the results of the second query with the results of the first.  You won't be able to do it with a single query.